# Grails User domain classes and cache true

Tags: grails, grails-orm

When should one use the following?

```
static mapping = {
cache true
}
```

I am tempted to add it to my domain classes User, UserRole and Role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cache after you have profiled your application and determined that caching information (such as your domain classes) would benefit your application. Data that is read only or changed very rarely should be considered for cache as long as it has a high usage.

The key is, profile your application, and only after that plan for caching where it makes sense. Don't just cache because it's available to you.